# How to export an object on a custom dbus using Python?

Tags: python, dbus

I want to provide dbus methods and signals on a custom bus (i.e. not SessionBus or SystemBus). If I start a test copy of the dbus-daemon from the command line, as described in [dbus-daemon man page](http://dbus.freedesktop.org/doc/dbus-daemon.1.html), like so:

```
dbus-daemon --session --print-address
```

then this returns for example the address:

```
unix:abstract=/tmp/dbus-vthAiAw4am,guid=60da6b6ef244a0dbdb9710a800002218
```

I can use this address in d-feet to "Connect to Other Bus", and there is nothing there. Now, I would like to claim a name on that bus and export objects to provide dbus methods and signals using Python. I have tried reading the code behind `dbus.service.BusName` where I would normally pass in the Session or System bus, but I simply get lost. Anyone know how to do this (if even possible)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looking at the source code for d-feet was of course an easier way to find the answer than browsing the entire dbus-python lib. An address like the one in the question could be used when claiming a bus name, by passing in a `dbus.bus.BusConnection` object with the address as argument, like so:

```
bus_name = dbus.service.BusName('my.testbus.test', 
    dbus.bus.BusConnection('unix:abstract=/tmp/dbus-vthAiAw4am'))
```

I can then export methods and emit signals on this bus.